# Trying to access array offset on value of type null while uploading image

Tags: php, laravel

this is my code to upload image

```
    $image=$request->file['image'];

    if(($image)){
        $image_name=hexdec(uniqid());
       $ext=strtolower($image->getClientOriginalExtention());
       $image_full_name=$image_name.'.'.$ext;
       $upload_path='public/image/';
       $image_url=$upload_path.$image_full_name;
       $success=$image->move($upload_path,$image_full_name);
       $data['image']=$image_url;
```

and then send to database

```
        DB::table('posts')->insert($data);
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your error page please

Comment: Change `file['image']` to a function call: `$image = $request->file('image');`

Answer (score 1):

you should use file method not as get as array so you should write :

```
$image=$request->file('image');
```

or retrive file from FileBag array :

```
$image=$request->files['image'];
```

Comment: perhaps you'd like to explain more?